# What is the most efficient way to check for path non-existence in a non-selective query?

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I have a graph model that contains three types of vertices (User, Group, Document) and two types of edges (member_of, permissions). The relationships can be expressed as:

```
User,Group --- member_of ---> Group  (depth can be arbitrary)
Group --- permissions ---> Document  (depth is 1)
```

I'm working to write a query that would answer "What are all of the users that have no permissions of any document?". This is a very non-selective query, as I'm not specifying an id for the User class.

I've come up with this solution:

```
SELECT id, name FROM User
LET $p = (
    SELECT expand(outE('permissions')) FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('member_of') FROM $parent.$current
    ) 
)
WHERE $p.size() = 0
```

This solution appears to work, but is taking between **12-15 seconds** to execute. Currently in my graph there are 10,000 Users, Groups and Documents each. There are ~10,000 permissions and ~50,000 member_of.

What is the most efficient way to check for path non-existence? Is there any way to improve the performance of my existing query or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: Before I answer, can you clarify a couple of things. (1) Can users and groups be members of groups? (2) Can a user be a member of more than 1 group?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to improve your query. First, it isn't necessary to expand the Permissions edges, you can simply check the amount of edges stored on the query. We can also limit this check so that it stops at the first group with permissions edges, rather than checking them all (credit to Luigi D for giving me this idea). Thus the query becomes as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM User
LET $p = (
    SELECT FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('Member_Of') FROM $parent.$current
    ) WHERE out('Permissions').size() > 0 LIMIT 1
)
WHERE $p.size() = 0
```

It's hard for me to check any query improvements without a sizeable dataset, but there may be a minute improvement by using the more explicit out_Member_Of and out_Permissions properties, rather than the out(field) functions.

There might be another opportunity to slightly improve the query by 'removing' the User record from the traverse results, thus reducing the amount of records checked by the WHERE clause. This could be done via

```
SELECT * FROM User
LET $p = (
    SELECT FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('Member_Of') FROM (SELECT out('Member_Of') FROM $parent.$parent.$current)
    ) WHERE out('Permissions').size() > 0 LIMIT 1
)
WHERE $p.size() = 0
```

The previous query can also be rearranged, although I suspect this one will be slower due to it checking all of the traversed results, rather than stopping at the first. It's just another option for you try.

```
SELECT * FROM User
LET $p = (TRAVERSE out('Member_Of') FROM (SELECT out('Member_Of') FROM $parent.$current))
WHERE $p.out('Permissions').size() = 0
```

---

**Now I'm going to diverge away from that query.** Perhaps it will be quicker to pre-compute if a group has access to docs, and then check each users group with the precomputed ones. This may save a lot of repetitive traversal.

I think the best way is to get all the Groups without docs. This way all groups with docs can be eliminated before traversing their other groups.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT FROM Group WHERE out('Permissions').size() = 0)
LET $p = (
    SELECT FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('Member_Of') FROM $parent.$current
    ) WHERE out('Permissions').size() > 0 LIMIT 1
)
WHERE $p.size() = 0
```

Perhaps creating and using an index will make the previous query even more performant, although the process currently seems a bit janky. Before you can create an index on out_Permissions, you need to create the property with `create property Group.out_Permissions LINKBAG`, and then you can create the index with `CREATE INDEX hasDocument ON Groups (out_Permissions, @rid) notunique METADATA {ignoreNullValues: false}` (creating the index this way seems strange, but it was the only way I could get it to work, hence my janky comment). You can then query the index with `select expand(rid) from index:hasDocument where key = null`, which will return all the Groups without permission edges, and that would replace `SELECT FROM Group WHERE out('Permissions').size() = 0` in the previous query.

So here is the query that gets the groups with docs, and checks the users against it. It correctly returns users without groups too.

```
SELECT expand($users)
LET $groups_without_docs = (
  SELECT FROM (SELECT FROM Group WHERE out('Permissions').size() = 0)
  LET $p = (
      SELECT FROM (
          TRAVERSE out('Member_Of') FROM $parent.$current
      ) WHERE out('Permissions').size() > 0 LIMIT 1
  )
  WHERE $p.size() = 0
),
$users = (
  SELECT FROM User 
  LET $groups = (SELECT expand(out('Member_Of')) FROM $current)
  WHERE $groups containsall (@rid in $parent.$groups_without_docs)
)
```

Note I think `$users = (SELECT FROM User WHERE out('Member_Of') containsall (@rid in $parent.$groups_without_docs))` should work, but it doesn't. I think this may be related to a bug I've previously posted, see https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4692.

*I am very interested to know if the various queries above improve your query, so please comment back.*

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this is a very non-selective query, so it's hard to optimize.

Have you tried to add a LIMIT to the inner query?

```
SELECT id, name FROM User
LET $p = (
    SELECT expand(outE('permissions')) FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('member_of') FROM $parent.$current
    ) LIMIT 1
)
WHERE $p.size() = 0
```

or even

```
SELECT id, name FROM User
LET $p = (
    SELECT sum(outE('permissions').size()) as s FROM (
        TRAVERSE out('member_of') FROM $parent.$current
    ) 
)
WHERE $p[0].s = 0
```